# How to change the expiration time of the data stored in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I already know that expired time can be set for the data stored in Apache IoTDB, so I want to know if I can change the expiration time of the data, and how to change it? Can this new expiration time be set to the data of any nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the expiration time of data by executing `set ttl` command again in Apache IoTDB.
And yes, you can set this time to the data of any node in IoTDB.